# Связка модального окна и jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

Имеется модальное окно, к нему приделана форма, хотелось бы понять, почему не получается прикрутить js проверку полей в модальном окне, они не проходят, пробовал привязывать прям к странице, прописывать асетсах, но js никак не реагирует.

вьюха модального окна

```
=javascript_include_tag 'autocomplete-rails.js'
#newModal.modal.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
  .modal-dialog{:role => "document"}
    = simple_form_for Feedback.new,url: feedb_main_index_path, method: 'post' do |f|
      .modal-content
        .modal-header
          %button.close{"aria-label" => "Закрыть", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
            %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} ×
          %h4#myModalLabel.modal-title Форма обратной связи

        .modal-body
          .well
            = label :theme_id,'Тема:'
            =f.select :theme_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Theme.order(:id), :id, :name), {include_blank: 'Выберите тему'}, class: 'form-control'
            = label :fio,'ФИО:'
            =f.text_field :fio, placeholder: 'Заполните поле ФИО', class: 'form-control'
            = label :tel,'Телефон:'
            =f.text_field :tel, placeholder: 'Заполните поле телефона', class: 'form-control'
            = label :email,'Email:'
            =f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Заполните поле электронной почты', class: 'form-control'
            = label :org_id,'Организация:'
            .text-success Введите маленькими буквами свою организацию для поиска её в базе
            =f.autocomplete_field :org_text, autocomplete_organization_name_main_index_path, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Заполните поле организации'

            %br
              .g-recaptcha{"data-sitekey" => ""}
        .modal-footer
          = f.submit 'Отправить', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block', id: 'btn_check'
```

вызов модального окна

```
  .feedback_foot
    .feedback_footer.text-center{"data-target" => "#newModal", "data-toggle" => "modal"}
```

js

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($('#feedback_tel').val() != '') {
            var pattern_tel = /^[0-9-+()]{6,16}$/;
            if (pattern_tel.test($('#feedback_tel').val())) {
                $('#feedback_tel').css({'border': '1px solid #569b44'});
            } else {
                $('#feedback_tel').css({'border': '1px solid #ff0000'});
                alert('Поле телефона должно содержать минимум 6 цифр');
                return false;
            }
        }else {
            return true;
        }

    });
});
```

или

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn_check').click(function () {
        if ($('#feedback_theme_id').val() != 0 || $('#feedback').val() != '' || $('#feedback_email').val() != '' || $('#feedback_tel').val() != '') {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert('Заполнено верно нажмите Ок');
            return true;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вроде сам, все работает, но при обработке запрос уходит, сохраняется в базу, мейлер тоже работает, но в аякс отвечает, что сообщение не доставлено. То есть error. с jquery сам потихоньку учусь. Почему проходит ошибка? и как её можно исправить и возможно, как сократить запись

```
$(function() {
        $('#new_feedback').submit(function (event) {
        // отменим стандартное действие браузера
          event.preventDefault();
          var form = $('#new_feedback').serialize();
          if ($('#feedback_theme_id').val() != 0 || $('#feedback_email').val() != '' || $('#feedback_tel').val() != '' || $('#feedback_org_text').val() != '' || $('#feedback_fio').val() != '' && $('#feedback_message').val() != '') {
            var pattern_phone = /^[0-9-()+]{6,16}$/;
            var pattern_email = /^[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9-\.]+\.([a-z]{2,3})?([a-z]{2,3})$/i;
            if(pattern_phone.test($('#feedback_tel').val())){
              $('#feedback_tel').css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
              if(pattern_email.test($('#feedback_email').val())){
                $('#feedback_email').css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                if ($('#feedback_theme_id').val() != 0){
                  $('#feedback_theme_id').css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                  if ($('#feedback_fio').val() != ''){
                    $('#feedback_fio').css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                    if ($('#feedback_org_text').val() != ''){
                      $('#feedback_org_text').css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                      if ($('#feedback_message').val() != ''){
                        $('#feedback_message').css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                        $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "/feedback",
                          data: form,
                          success: function (data) {
                            alert('Спасибо за обращение');
                            $("#newModal").modal('hide');
                            console.log('gotov');
                          },
                          error: function (data) {
                            alert('Форма не отправлена');
                            console.log('ne gotov');
                          }
                        });    
                      }
                      else{
                        $('#feedback_message').css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                        alert('Поле сообщения не заполнено');
                      }
                    }
                    else{
                      $('#feedback_org_text').css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                      alert('Поле организации не заполнено');
                    }
                  }
                  else{
                    $('#feedback_fio').css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                    alert('Поле ФИО не заполнено');
                    return false;
                  }
                }
                else {
                  $('#feedback_theme_id').css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                  alert('Поле темы не заполнено');
                  return false;
                }
              }
              else {
                $('#feedback_email').css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                alert('Поле email заполнено некорректно');
                return false;
              }
            } else {
              $('#feedback_tel').css({'border': '1px solid #ff0000'});
              alert('Поле контактного телефона должно содержать минимум 6 цифр');
              return false;
            }
          }
          else {
            alert('Заполните все поля');
            return false;

          }

        });
      });
```